# Python code works when calling a method but not when running a programm

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to make my own python program for converting degrees Fahrenheit or Celsius to another unit. I'm a python newbie. This is my code

```
def f_to_c(temp):
        return (temp - 32) * 5 / 9
def c_to_f(temp):
        return temp * 9 / 5 + 32
def execute():
        what = input("Unit you want to convert? (f/c) ")
        while (what == "c" or what == "C" or what == "f" or what == "F"):
            if what == "c" or what == "C":
                temp = float(input("Enter degrees Celsius: "))
                return c_to_f(temp)
            else:
                temp = float(input("Enter degrees Fahrenheit: "))
                return f_to_c(temp)
        else:
            return execute()
```

This part of the code works after executing in IDLE and running execute() method. But if I add:

```
execute()
```

to the end of my .py file, there is an error. It gets to the second question (degrees Fahrenheit or Celsius). It just breaks. Is there a way to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `(what == "c" or what == "C" or what == "f" or what == "F")` == `(what.lower() in 'cf')`

Comment: You mean that there is a traceback, or that the console just closes, or that nothing happens?

Comment: @Elazar Thanks.@Martijin Pieters Nothing happens. I enter a number and it does nothing. just goes to new line and I can call a method again

Comment: Does it work if you change `execute()` to `main()`?

Comment: you don't need the while at all... you actually need a tight `while True... if (..): break` around the `input()` line. avoid using recursion here. (it's not really you problem though)

Comment: @John: Why would that make it work? Python attaches no special meaning to `main()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm still a beginner at Python myself; trying to learn by asking questions. :)

Comment: `what.lower() in 'cf'` will be `True` for `''` input resulting in a default of Fahrenheit (for python 2.7 anyway).

Comment: @dansalmo you are right (in python3 too). `in` for `str` is actually `substring of`... I didn't think about it. You'll need `what.lower() in set('cf')`.

Comment: `'_cCfF'.find()` would work.

Comment: @Elazar I don't quite get the `while True... if (..): break`

Comment: I can't write here full example, and it's not an answer to your question. but i will try to give an example anyway: `while True:; w=input(); if w in set('cCfF'): break` is the only part you need to loop on (`;` as a line seperator here, and the `if` is *inside* the loop)

Comment: @dansalmo only if compared by `> 0`. it's not directly What You Want To Do.

Comment: @Elazar, I think `'_cCfF'.find()` works fine for `while` or `if` blocks as well.

Comment: @dansalmo how will you use it, exactly? please show the whole statement.

Comment: @Elazar, `while '_cCfF'.find(what):` instead of `while what.lower() in set('cf'):`.  I guess leaving out the `what` var made it confusing.

Comment: @dansalmo this test will fail only if the input is `_`, and will succeed otherwise. `'_cCfF'.find('x')==-1`. maybe you wanted `'cCfF'.find(what)+1`. But this is not readable.

Comment: @Elazar, Oops, you are right, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, you are doing nothing with the return value of `execute()`. Add a call to `print()` so you can see the result of your conversion, and perhaps wait for a keypress:

```
print(execute())
input('Press any key')
```

With the `input()` call the Windows console will remain open until you are done reading what the program has to print. It is not needed when running in IDLE.

Comment: Thanks. It worked fantastic. Couldn't figure out why it works one way but not another

Answer (score 1):

you're missing this lines at the end:

```
result = execute()
print(result)
```

You have to call your *main* function in your case *execute()*.
Now you can print the result directly in *execute()* or you return the result (you're doing it) and store the returned value into a var and print it. ;)